# Compare two values for rows that match multiple criteria

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2016

This is a simplified version of my data table:

```
ID   Group   Type      Category   Limit
1    1       I         A          50   
2    1       I         B          50
3    2       I         A          30
4    2       I         B          30
5    2       II        A          40
6    2       II        B          20
```

The task would be to add another column that checks for each row if the "Limit" is identical for all rows that have both the same "group" and the same "type".

In this example data set, this would be the desired table:

```
ID   Group   Type      Category   Limit   Check
1    1       I         A          50      Same
2    1       I         B          50      Same
3    2       I         A          30      Same
4    2       I         B          30      Same
5    2       II        A          40      Different
6    2       II        B          20      Different
```

How would the formula for the new column "Check" look like?

Just started using Microsoft Access and help would be much appreciated - thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
IIF(Nz(DLookup("ID","TableName","Group=" & [Group] & " AND Type='" & [Type] & "' AND Limit<>" & [Limit]),0)=0,"Same","Different")
```